# What to put in this method? JAVA basic

Tags: java

Can anyone help me out? I am trying to figure out what to put in this getLecture body where the question marks are:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Schedule 
{
    private ArrayList<Lecture> lectures;

    public Schedule(ArrayList<Lecture> lectures)
    {
        lectures = new ArrayList<Lecture>();

    }
    public Lecture getLecture(long date, long time)
    {
        
        ???
    }
    public ArrayList<Lecture> getLectures() {
        return lectures;
    }
    public void addLecture(Lecture lecture)
        {
            lectures.add(lecture);
        }
    public void removeLecture(Lecture lecture)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < lectures.size(); i++)
            {
                if(lectures.get(i) == lecture)
                {
                    lectures.remove(i);

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I am trying to compare the time,  with the parameters given to that method, then  to make a for loop going through a list, preferably a for each loop. Inside of the loop I need to take the time of the Lecture object created inside the method, and compare it to the time of the Lecture from the list. This is the lecture class:

```
package application;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Lecture {
    private String message;
    private long time;
    private long date;
    private ArrayList<Object> materials;

    public Lecture() {
        int date;
        int time;
    }

    public String sendMessage(String message) {
        return message;

    }
    public void uploadMaterial(Object material) {
        materials.add(material);
          
    }
    public Object getMaterial(Object material) {
        return material;
    }

    public void removeMaterial(Object material) {
        for(int i = 0; i < materials.size(); i++)
        {
            if(material == materials.get(i))
                materials.remove(i);    
    }
    }

    public long getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(long time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    public long getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(long date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
}
```

Comment: Side note: you probably don't want to use `==` to compare instances, but rather `#equals()`, see https://medium.com/qudini-engineering/java-object-identity-or-how-to-override-equals-hashcode-and-compareto-400fd4547fe0.

Comment: Another side note: why are you representing a date as a `long`? Check out the [docs](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html) for dealing with dates and times.

Comment: What is `getLecture()` supposed to do? From the lectures found in the schedule, return the one that matches both date and time? What should it return if there is no such matching lecture? Return null? Create such a lecture and add it to the schedule? What if there are multiple lectures with the same date and time?

Comment: You've described precisely what you need to do. What stops you from doing that?